# Mathematics problems clock

Tags: recreational-mathematics, education

Long ago, I had an idea of creating (actually, labeling) a clock that will have, instead of the numbers 1,…,12, important mathematical problems whose solution turned out to be that number. Such a clock could be awesome for mathematics departments.

This is a call for such problems.
Please, consider posting problems for numbers that are not well-addressed yet.

Comment: E.g. see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16066/designing-an-irrational-numbers-wall-clock/16099#16099 for some math clocks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I look for problems that have an exact solution among 1,2,...,12. Also, I'd rather something of the form "the dimension of ..." rather than "the first digit of $\sqrt{2}$". The deeper and more surprising the theorem is, the better it will be for my purpose.

Comment: The image search of google for "math clock" does find some more designs.

Comment: This site has a systematic collection: [link](http://www.sbcrafts.net/clocks/)

Comment: The [tautological clock](http://www.komplexify.com/images/2009/MathClock11.jpg) from [this site](http://komplexify.com/blog/2009/10/17/1t-once-upon-a-time/) is my favourite so far.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like you want wordier, deeper labels, rather than just complicated expressions. How about something like "4: highest order of polynomial equation with algebraic solution"? Or "6: smallest friendly number"? Or: 10: "smallest number for which its status as a friendly number is unknown"?

Comment: @mvw: Cute clocks, but none containing any serious mathematical problem as a label or an hour. Similar answer re the tautological clock.

Comment: @mb7744: You are right, but the problems you mention are too elementary and simple. I am interested in deep mathematical theorems.

Comment: @BoazTsaban Once you got your dream clock, please post an image here.

Comment: @mvw: With the votes so far, no much chance for enough contributions. The dream is likely to remain a dream. Judging from the answers and my preferences, it seems MathOverflow should have been the right forum for this problem. But MO refuses questions that are not research questions. So, unfortunately, I know of no alternative platform for this question.

Comment: I beg to differ that Abel-Ruffini is so trivial. But see my answer for more.

Answer (score 0):

These have some your numbers in them...

What do you get when you link primes, transcendentals, $0$, unity, subtraction, and equality?
$$e^{2 \pi i}-1=0$$
A root inside a root inside a root...
$$2=\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}}}}}}$$

What do you get when you sum all the natural numbers? Not what you think according to the Riemann zeta function.
\begin{equation}
1+2+3+4...={-1 \over 12}
\end{equation}

Comment: Most people would make some kind of notational indicator that they were referring to "non-standard" summation, unless they were just trolling for a reaction.

Comment: @JonathanHebert I specifically referred to the Riemann method, i.e Riemann zeta function.

Comment: Sorry, I meant no offense. I've seen a lot of writers end the statement with a "fancy R", for example.

Comment: @JonathanHebert No worries, deleted my comment. You think adding the Cauchy theorem for complex integrals is better than the nested root example of 2?

Comment: This is not the kind of problems I look for. I need real, deep mathematical theorems, at the level of research mathematics.

Comment: @BoazTsaban I hope you understand that you just called Euler's theorem and $\zeta(-1)$ trivial.

Comment: @Zach466920: The theorem should not be something every undergraduate knows, to start with. Also, if you know what $e^{\pi i\alpha}$ means, Euler's Theorem _is_ trivial. The depth there is not the equality, but the meaning. As of $\zeta(-1)$, this does not give a whole number and again the equality is not the main point here.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a good source for you, provided you are looking for wordy yet mathematically interesting properties. The wikipedia pages for the integers from 1 to 12, entitled 'n_(number)', all have interesting mathematical facts about those numbers in the "Mathematics" section. For instance, [7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7_%28number%29#Mathematics):

> - Seven is the lowest natural number that cannot be represented as the sum of the squares of three integers.
> - n = 7 is the first natural number for which the next statement does not hold: "Two nilpotent endomorphisms from Cn with the same minimal polynomial and the same rank are similar."
> - 7 is the only dimension, besides the familiar 3, in which a vector cross product can be defined.
> - 7 is the lowest dimension of a known exotic sphere, although there may exist as yet unknown exotic smooth structures on the 4-dimensional sphere.
> - etc.

Comment: This is the only relevant answer for my purposes thus far, and a good one. Unfortunately, some of the numbers (e.g., 1) do not contain any theorem/problem whose answer is that number.